# The class 'java.util.HashMap$Node' does not have a writable property 'key'

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

How to solve this issue: 
I want to Change key of my bean map with celledit feature from primefaces. 
For editing the value of map it works well.

For changing the key i get following error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: The class 'java.util.HashMap$Node' does not have a writable property 'key'.

<p:dataTable id="breaktime" var="item" value="#{breakTimeDataActions.map.entrySet().toArray()}"
    editable="true" editMode="cell" >

    <f:facet name="header">
    </f:facet>

    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{breakTimeDataActions.onCellEdit}"
    update=":form:msgs" />

    <p:column headerText="#{texts['breaktime.hours']}">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.key}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:spinner  value="#{item.key}" min="0" max="24"  converter="javax.faces.Integer" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{texts['breaktime.minute']}">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{breakTimeDataActions.map[item.key]}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:spinner value="#{breakTimeDataActions.map[item.key]}" min="0" max="24"  converter="javax.faces.Integer" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: The real question here is why are you trying to change the key of a `HashMap` node? It's a violation of the fundamental contract that keys are read-only.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get an error is that the keys in an entrySet are immutable.  The `entrySet()` method returns a `Set<Map.Entry>`.  If you look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) for `Map.Entry` you will see:

- a `V getValue()` method,
- a `void setValue(V)` method,
- a `K getKey()` method, but
- no `void setKey(K)` method

Basically, the `key` property is read-only per the JavaBeans convention.  That's actually a good thing, because if you *could* modify a `key` in an `Set<Map.Entry>` you would have the difficult problem of what to do if the new `key` was the same as the `key` of another entry in the original map.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. My idea was to overwrite the key. I would like to display key value as hours --> minutes. I thought a map is a good solution. In my JPA model a have map for this. I don't know how to represent this in jsf and the bean.

Comment: Are you sure that what you are representing is a mapping of hour to minutes?  From your description, it sounds like it is a set of hour / minute pairs.

Comment: I also thougt about this. You mean to create an own class, with hour and Minute properties ? For Example Set<OwnClass> intervals